# Borel Measurable Function but not Lebesgue Measurable

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Can someone explain to me why this function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ given by $f(x) = (x,0)$ is $\mathcal B$-$\mathcal B^2$-measurable but not $\mathcal L$-$\mathcal L^2$-measurable, where $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal L$ denote the Borel and Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, respectively?

Regards

Comment: Since I'm making a substantial edit to the title over 4 years after the question was asked and answered, I'm putting in a comment about it here (anticipating that the edit will be approved):  The usual meaning of Lebesgue measurability for functions is Lebesgue–Borel, but here we want Lebesgue–Lebesgue.  Indeed, the question title confused me at first, since *every* Borel–Borel measurable function is Lebesgue–Borel measurable, but not Lebesgue–Lebesgue measurable.  Having put in the missing second half in the Lebesgue case, I put it in the Borel case too, for symmetry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map $f$ is continuous, so the preimage of a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Thus $f$ is Borel to Borel measurable.

Let $N\subseteq[0,1]$ be a Lebesgue nonmeasurable set. Then $N\times\{0\}$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ because the Lebesgue measure is complete, $N\times\{0\}\subseteq[0,1]\times\{0\}$, and $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Then $f^{-1}(N\times\{0\})=N$ shows that $f$ is not Lebesgue to Lebesgue measurable.